# Amcharts 5 - Smoothed line chart - two line charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, linechart, amcharts5

Im dealing with this problem.
I have smoothed line chart from amcharts v5.

And everything is working properly until i want to add second line to the chart. It only displays one line chart. And i need to add second line to the same chart.

If I change data values to another chart. It is working fine but same problem, only one line.

So my question is, how to add second line into same chart.

```
am5.ready(function() {
// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
panX: true,
panY: true,
wheelX: "panX",    
wheelY: "zoomX",
pinchZoomX:true
}));
// Add cursor
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
behavior: "none"
}));
cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

function generateDataInvestice(roky,investice) {
   value = investice;
   return {
   date: roky,
   value: value
};
}

function generateDatasInvestice(count,i) {
  var data = [];
  var investice = 5;
  for (var i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
    data.push(generateDataInvestice(i,investice));
  }
  return data;
}

//generate uver
function generateDataUver(roky,uver) {
  value = uver;
  return {
    date: roky,
    value: value
  };
}
function generateDatasUver(count,i) {
  var data = [];
  var uver = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
    data.push(generateDataUver(i,uver));
  }
  return data;
}
// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  maxDeviation: 1,
  baseInterval: {
    count: 1
  },
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
  pan:"zoom"
}),
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
}));

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  maxDeviation:1,
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
  pan:"zoom"
})
}));

// Add series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries.new(root, {
  name: "Series",
  xAxis: xAxis,
  yAxis: yAxis,
  valueYField: "value",
  valueXField: "date",
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    labelText: "{valueY}"
  })
}));

series.fills.template.setAll({
  visible: true,
  fillOpacity: 0.2
});

series.bullets.push(function() {
  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    locationY: 0,
    sprite: am5.Circle.new(root, {
      radius: 4,
      stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
      strokeWidth: 2,
      fill: series.get("fill")
    })
  });
});

var data = generateDatasInvestice(30,0);
var data_uver = generateDatasUver(30,0);
series.data.setAll(data,data_uver);

series.appear(30);
chart.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
```

Here is working soluiton on codepen: https://codepen.io/tom-august/pen/KKQLgbm

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your data, you should have several value fields like so:

```js
var data = [
  {
    date: new Date("2022-12-27").getTime(),
    value1: 10,
    value2: 20
  },
  {
    date: new Date("2022-12-28").getTime(),
    value1: 20,
    value2: 30
  },
  {
    date: new Date("2022-12-29").getTime(),
    value1: 10,
    value2: 20
  }
];
```

Then you need to create a series for each line that you want to display, associating each series with the corresponding value field. This can be done using a function:

```js
function createSeries(name, field) {
  var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries.new(root, {
    name: name,
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueXField: "date",
    valueYField: field
  }));

  series.data.setAll(data);
}
  
createSeries("Series 1", "value1");
createSeries("Series 2", "value2");
```

```js
am5.ready(function() {

  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));

  var data = [
    {
      date: new Date("2022-12-27").getTime(),
      value1: 10,
      value2: 20
    },
    {
      date: new Date("2022-12-28").getTime(),
      value1: 20,
      value2: 30
    },
    {
      date: new Date("2022-12-29").getTime(),
      value1: 10,
      value2: 20
    }
  ];

  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
    baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
  }));

  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));
  
  function createSeries(name, field) {
    var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.SmoothedXLineSeries.new(root, {
      name: name,
      xAxis: xAxis,
      yAxis: yAxis,
      valueXField: "date",
      valueYField: field
    }));

    series.data.setAll(data);
  }
  
  createSeries("Series 1", "value1");
  createSeries("Series 2", "value2");

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```